# Upgrade from 3.3.6 to 3.4.5 not possible

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade

I am using the German Joomla version 3.3.6 an wish to upgrade to 3.4.5, but in the backend my system says that I have the most recent version installed.

If I go to **Components >> Joomla Update >> Clear Cache**, I get the following output:

[image]

Then I was trying to install Joomla 3.4.5 Update package via the Extensions Manager.

I first get the following dialog:

[image]

**Pushing the blue button does NOTHING.**

Comment: Have you purged the cache? Logged in/out again? On the Extension Manager page, click on the Update tab to make it the active tab, and then click on the Purge Cache icon link in in the upper right corner of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

In your Jomla backend, go to:

**Components** (top menu) >> **Joomla Update** >> **Clear Cache**

Once done, there should be an update available.

If not, you can download the [Joomla 3.4.5 Update package](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.4.5/Joomla_3.4.5-Stable-Update_Package.zip) and install it via the Extensions Manager like you would any other extension.

Hope this helps

Comment: please see the updated question above.

Answer (score 2):

You can try enabling `fopen` on your hosting account, if it isn't enabled. This is usually done by adding a file called `php.ini` in your Joomla site's root, then add the following line inside it:

```
allow_url_fopen = on
```

(some hosts have different methods to change php settings, e.g. GoDaddy requires the file to be called `php5.ini`)

Check if `fopen` has been enabled by going to **System >> System Information**, then select the tab **PHP Information** and look for `allow_url_fopen`, it should say `On`.

### Other things to try:

1. Go to **System >> Clear cache**, select all Cache Groups (if any) and hit "Delete"
2. Go to **Extensions >> Manage** and select "Update" from the left hand side menu. Click "Clear Cache"
3. Go to **Components >> Joomla Update** and click "Clear Cache"

If everything fails, you can try uploading the update package (or even the full installation package) to your hosting account. Unpack it to your Joomla root directory, overwriting any existing files.

**Remember to always make a complete backup of your site before updating.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have exhausted all avenues for installing via the Extension manager ( https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Updating_from_an_existing_version ) then another way to install a via FTP ( https://docs.joomla.org/Ftp-update-not-working )

Apart from obviously making a site & database backup before attempting this, I would make a duplicate install of the current site and try it out first. This is NOT the recommended way to update Joomla 3.x

Also, these guys might be able to help you further. https://www.jgerman.de/downloads/joomla-34-auf-deutsch.html