# Unable to update Joomla core package

Tags: joomla-3.x, update

When I go to Joomla! Update it is showing the following:

> No updates available. You are on the "Default" update channel. Through
>   this channel you'll receive notifications for all updates of the
>   current Joomla! release (3.x)
>
> You already have the latest Joomla version, 3.6.5.

I know there is version 3.8.3, but it is not appearing, even when I purge the cache. I have checked the Directory Permissions and they are all showing up as writable. I do have the error log set to maximum but there are no error showing.

Comment: As per https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/14176/120 you may need to clear the cache at System -> Clear Cache and also at Extensions -> Manage -> Update -> Clear Cache before the Joomla update will be offered.

Answer (score 1):

First check that you meet the minimum requirements, especially as far as the PHP version is concerned. Make sure you have at least PHP 5.3.10 (recommended: PHP 7.2.17). Oftentimes the reason you don't see an update is that your server simply does not meet the minimum requirements.

If you are sure your server supports Joomla! 3.9.6, the actually latest release at the time of this writing and not 3.8.3 as you mistakenly said, first take a backup of your site. Then follow Method C [per the Joomla! documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5).

If I recall correctly, your Joomla version also includes the Upload & Update feature I contributed to the Joomla! Update component. If this is the case we can follow Method D, not mentioned in the documentation:

- Take a backup of your site. If things go wrong this is your only way to restore your site back to normal.
- Download the latest update package from 3.x ([e.g Joomla! 3.x to 3.9.6](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.9.6-rc/Joomla_3.9.6-rc-Release_Candidate-Update_Package.zip))
- Go to Components, Joomla! Update, Upload & Update
- Choose the ZIP file you just downloaded and click on Upload & Install
- It will ask you to re-enter your Super User credentials. Please do that, it's a security check.
- Joomla! Update will now use the ZIP file to update your site to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem related to the update xml.

Have you tried to do a manual update?

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Upgrading_from_Joomla_3.4.x_to_3.5